# Spring Data @Query use VARCHAR instead of NVARCHAR

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

The code that I posted is not the code that our companies uses, it is just example code to correctly illustrate the problem.

I have the following Spring Data Query:

```java
@Query(value = "FROM CustomerTable WHERE Name.firstName = ?1 AND Name.lastName = ?2")
List<Customer> findByName(String firstName, String lastName);
```

For entity `Customer`:

```java
public class Customer {
  Name name;
  // ...
}
```

and `Name`:

```java
public class Name {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  // ...
}
```

This works okay, but Spring data passes these parameters as `NVARCHAR` instead of `VARCHAR`. Therefore, the DB has to perform expensive conversion that is very expensive.

How can I make sure that Spring Data passes these parameters as `VARCHAR` instead of `NVARCHAR`?

EDIT: The way I know that it is being sent in as NVARCHAR is by using the SQL Profiler. This provides me with this info:

```
exec sp_executesql N'select customer.id as id1_7_, ...
from customers custome0_ where custome0_.first_name=@P0 and custome0_.last_name=@P1',N'@P0 nvarchar(4000),@P1 nvarchar(4000)',N'Tom',N'Cruise'
```

Comment: What hibernate version and hibernate dialect do you use?

Comment: Dialect is `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect`. We are using Spring Boot `2.1.12.RELEASE`, and from the [maven central page I can see that the Hibernate version for that release is 5.3.15.Final](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/2.1.12.RELEASE)

Comment: May I know how you know Spring data passes these parameters as NVARCHAR instead of VARCHAR.?

Comment: Sure, I'm using SQL Profiler. I added the information to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to circumvent the expensive conversion by changing the column types in the database to `NVARCHAR`, but then I also had to add a `@Type` annotation to the `Name` instance variable on my `Customer` entity:

```java
public class Customer {
  @Type(type="org.hibernate.type.StringNVarcharType")
  Name name;
  // ...
}
```

This works, but it's not the preferred solution, as it is not part of the JPA specification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@Nationalized` annotation on `Name name` in the `Customer` entity

Answer (score 0):

You can set property `sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false` in `spring.datasource.url` inside application.properties file.
Parameter will be pass like:
`(@P0 varchar(8000))` not `(@P0 nvarchar(4000))`